# Increasing and Decreasing

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

> 1, 0, 3, 11, 15, 13, 17, 24, 23

I believe this is sufficient information to find the 9th through 12th numbers in this sequence

**What are the 9th, 10th, 11th, and 12th terms?**

Comment: Hope this doesn't turn out to be too broad.

Comment: That's my thought

Comment: It looks to me like the **9th** number is "23". (Or is that the **11th** one? Counting is hard!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The next numbers in the sequence are:

> 73, 101, 104, 103
>  The lowest numbers that have $n$ characters when written out, $n$ starting from $n=3$

Full list goes:

> 1 -> ONE
>  0 -> ZERO
>  3 -> THREE
>  11 -> ELEVEN
>  15 -> FIFTEEN
>  13 -> THIRTEEN
>  17 -> SEVENTEEN
>  24 -> TWENTY-FOUR
>  23 -> TWENTY-THREE
>  73 -> SEVENTY-THREE
>  101 -> ONE HUNDRED ONE
>  104 -> ONE HUNDRED FOUR
>  103 -> ONE HUNDRED THREE

Comment: Hmm i see now that next to 15 missing, 7 should be 3 as well. Maybe I'm missing something myself...

Comment: I don't make puzzles well at school T_T sorry

Comment: Haha :D Nice catch @Levieux +1

Comment: Actually 14 should be 13 as well I see now

Comment: These little errors did prevent anyone from looking the series up on oeis.org, though :P

Comment: Yeah [A134629](http://oeis.org/A134629)

Comment: In British English I think it would be seventy-three, three thousand, eleven thousand, fifteen thousand.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime And then one hundred and one?

Comment: @Levieux Yes, after those it goes back to the terms of the American English sequence for n-3. I don't know when the next time something different happens is -- I guess that continues up to the hundred thousands, when BrE starts to use six more letters than AmE.

Comment: @Levieux It's not a bug, it's a feature `:)`

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to this is:

> 1, 0, 7, 11, 14, 17, 24, 23, **30**, **34**, **37**, **40**, **47**, **46**, etc

Which is simply

> Doing the sequence from 0 forward again (+7, +4, +3, +3, +7, -1, etc)

I think this may have other solutions though.